# Python + Sqlite 3. How to construct queries?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a python script that constructs valid sqlite queries. I want to avoid SQL Injection, so I cannot use `'%s'`. I've found how to execute queries, `cursor.execute('sql ?', (param))`, but I want how to get the parsed `sql param`. It's not a problem if I have to execute the query first in order to obtain the last query executed.

Comment: I think that I'll use something like sqlalchemy, and then doing a pickle.dump, which will store the object in a file, so I can use later the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to transmit changes to the database to another computer, why do they have to be expressed as SQL strings?  Why not pickle the query string and the parameters as a tuple, and have the other machine also use SQLite parameterization to query its database?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not after just parameter substitution, but full construction of the SQL, you have to do that using string operations on your end. The `?` replacement always just stands for a value. Internally, the SQL string is compiled to SQLite's own bytecode (you can find out what it generates with `EXPLAIN thesql`) and `?` replacements are done by just storing the value at the correct place in the value stack; varying the query structurally would require different bytecode, so just replacing a value wouldn't be enough.

Yes, this does mean you have to be *ultra-careful*. If you don't want to allow updates, try opening the DB connection in read-only mode.

Comment: All I want is to being able to recreate the database in other computers. Since I want to use the less bandwith possible, I need to create partial dumps (which will contain the changes) and transfer them over the net. Is a good idea to use something like sqlalchemy, store the objects with pickle, and use them in the remote computer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method.

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'hello'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = (symbol,)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```

More reference is [in the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Yes, but I want to get the query, not the result. For example, "SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=tralala".

Answer (score 0):

> I want how to get the parsed 'sql param'.

It's all open source so you have full access to the code doing the parsing / sanitization. Why not just reading this code and find out how it works and if there's some (possibly undocumented) implementation that you can reuse ?

Comment: I tried that too. I ended at a "import _sqlite3", which I think corresponds to a '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so' file